# keep only one duplicate value in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to delete duplicate rows based on two columns in SQL:

FROM

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| A | hola |
| A | hello |
| B | arigato |
| B | adios |

TO

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| A | hola |
| B | arigato |

In a nutshell, remove ID duplicates and keep any of their TEXT strings.

The next SQL script didn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table_name
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: tag your database

Comment: General solution: GROUP BY, MAX().

Comment: How do you know which `TEXT` value is correct?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, "_and keep any of their TEXT strings_".

Answer (score 0):

Using `rank` is a possible solution for your use-case.

```
select ID, TEXT
from (
    select *,
           rank() over(partition by ID order by TEXT) as rnum
    from table_name
) a
where rnum = 1
```

Depending on the database you are using (postgresql, mysql, mssql, etc.), you could alternatively use `row_number()` to do a similar ranking and selecting of rows.

```
select ID, TEXT
from (
    select *,
           row_number() over(partition by ID order by TEXT) as rnum
    from table_name
) a
where rnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`. [here is some doc about GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: You need to an aggregate function for the text column.

Comment: @jarlh it depends on the DBMS.

Comment: When you say it, I remember some products have had serious GROUP BY problems.